# Integrating Google Calendar/fullcalendar.io into a page on Squarespace

Tags: javascript, html, css, squarespace

My group doesn't yet have a published site, so we're still working on edit mode, and we're trying to integrate fullcalendar. We're referencing [this](https://codepen.io/bifrost04/pen/BEJbva) to do so. So far, what we've done is gone to page settings> advanced and added in this code to the head:

```
<style> 
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
  }

  #calendar {
    max-width: 900px;
    margin: 40px auto;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'list', 'googleCalendar' ],
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,listYear'
    },

    displayEventTime: false, // don't show the time column in list view

    // To make your own Google API key, follow the directions here:
    // http://fullcalendar.io/docs/google_calendar/
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'AIzaSyDcnW6WejpTOCffshGDDb4neIrXVUA1EAE',

    // US Holidays
    events: 'en.usa#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com',

    eventClick: function(arg) {

      // opens events in a popup window
      window.open(arg.event.url, '_blank', 'width=700,height=600');

      // prevents current tab from navigating
      arg.jsEvent.preventDefault();
    }

  });

  calendar.render();
});
</script>
```

Then, we went back to edit the page, added in a code block, selected html, and typed in this html:

```
<div id='calendar'></div>
```

But nothing displays. Are we doing something wrong?

Comment: If you find that you get no replies or answers, consider adding a link to the page in question, which makes it much easier to identify issues. If your Squarespace site is in trial mode, you can set the "Site Visibility" to "Password" and provide that view-only password so that others can see it.

Comment: @Brandon the website is https://helicon-star-7w5x.squarespace.com/events and the password is tbfwebsite2021, maybe that helps to see it? 
I know its bc I haven't properly imported fullcalendar, but Im not sure how importing libraries works in squarespace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the page you have setup, you're correct that you've not loaded the necessary external libraries. So that's the first step.

To see the external libraries that are being used, you can go to settings within Codepen. See here:

[image]

Those external libraries need to be loaded **before** your custom code. So where you have your `<script>` for loading JQuery, you'd add:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@4.0.2/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/daygrid@4.0.1/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/list@4.0.1/main.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/google-calendar@4.0.1/main.min.js"></script>
```

See [this Codepen](https://codepen.io/ignbrndn/pen/XWpVdqM) for a modified example where the external libraries are visibly loaded as part of the HTML.

Then, make sure that you're placing your JavaScript (including the `script` elements mentioned above) within **Footer** code injection, not Header.

That'll at least get things loaded.

As an aside, the code, as written, doesn't seem to require JQuery, though perhaps some of your other code on your site does.

Comment: ohh I see, didnt know you could find those on codepen. I think though I still cant see the calendar? I get errors from the get requests :(

Comment: OK, two things: First, within the answer above, I changed the URLs in the `script` elements because they weren't loading as desired. So, use those URLs instead. Second, see the note I added about using Footer (not Header) code injection. Because your code is currently in header code injection, it is executing before your `<div id="calendar"></div>` element exists on the page. So move your code to Footer injection, so that it runs after that element exists within the DOM.

Comment: @Brandon ty for following up! I still cant see it sadly, but I'm wondering if all the style code needs to go in the footer as well. I'm not sure what's going wrong lol

Comment: OK, that's good. Now we can see that you have an error `"a is undefined"`. That is caused by using the latest versions of those libraries, rather than the versions in the Codepen that you followed. So, I've updated the URLs of the `<script>` elements in the answer to the old versions, as in the original Codepen. You can see in the Codepen that I linked to in my answer, that it is now working. The `<style>` element is fine in the header.

Comment: ohhh that made it load, although the formatting is rather janky. Sorry to bother you again, but how would I fix the formatting? I went into developer console and it said it failed to load the API so I regenerated the API key and put in our own calendar ID, but the formatting stayed the same. I tried editing the size tags in style, but to no avail

Comment: Unfortunately, the password has changed so the site can no longer be viewed.